# sql query to dynamically add fiscal month using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_sp_GetDMActivityTrackerReport]
@CoachId VARCHAR(7),
@Month INT,
@FiscalYear INT
AS 
BEGIN    

INSERT @FiscalMonth (ID,Month,NbHolidays,MonthDate,TotalDays)
EXECUTE dbo._sp_GetFiscalMonths @Month, @FiscalYear

SELECT PreparationID,CoachId,UserID, MemberID,
[Rep Name], isnull(April,0) April, isnull(May,0) May, isnull(June,0)June,
isnull(July,0) July, isnull(August,0) August, isnull(September,0) September, 
isnull(October,0) October, isnull(November,0) November,
isnull(December,0) December, isnull(January,0) January, isnull(February,0) February,
isnull(March,0) March,isnull((isnull(November,0) + isnull(December,0) + 
isnull(January,0) + isnull(February,0) + isnull(March,0) + isnull(April,0) +
isnull(May,0) + isnull(June,0) + isnull(July,0) + isnull(August,0) +
isnull(September,0) + isnull(October,0)),0) as [Total Field TIME] 

FROM
(
SELECT up.PreparationID,tt.UserId [CoachId],up.UserID, utm.MemberID, 
(ui.FirstName + ' ' + ui.LastName) AS [Rep Name],DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) [Month], sum(nft.Quantity) [Days]

FROM TransferedTime tt
INNER JOIN UPreparation up ON tt.PreparationID = up.PreparationID 
RIGHT JOIN UTeamMembers utm ON tt.UserId = utm.CoachID AND utm.MemberID = up.UserID
INNER JOIN UserInfo ui ON utm.MemberID = ui.UserID
LEFT JOIN NonFieldTime nft ON nft.UserId = tt.UserId 
AND tt.MonthPeriodFrom = nft.MonthPeriodStart
AND datename(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) + '-'+ substring(datename(Year,nft.MonthPeriodStart),3,2) IN 
(SELECT Month +'-' +substring(datename(Year,MonthDate),3,2) [Months] FROM @FiscalMonth)
WHERE utm.MemberID IN (SELECT MemberID FROM UTeamMembers WHERE CoachID = @CoachId)
GROUP BY up.PreparationID,tt.UserId,up.UserID, utm.MemberID,
(ui.FirstName + ' ' + ui.LastName),DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart)) src 
pivot 
(
sum(Days)
for Month in (April, May, June, July, August, September, October,November, December, January, February, March)
)
piv 

@Fiscalmonth returns:
Id, Month, NbHolidays, MonthDate
1   April     1 4/1/2012
2   May   2 5/1/2012 
3   June      3 6/1/2012
4   July      4 7/1/2012
5   August    5 8/1/2012
6   September 6 9/1/2012
7   October   7 10/1/2012
8   November  8 11/1/2012
9   December  9 12/1/2012
10  January   10    1/1/2013
11  February  11    2/1/2013
12  March     12    3/1/2013
```

I have a stored procedure which generate report according to the fiscal year.
here fiscal year and fiscal month comes from the database now I am facing problem in generating this report dynamically as you can see i had fixed the months year which is not a good practice i want it to some way that if i changed the fiscal month in the database then my report reflect accordingly.

Comment: So you want to essentially do exactly what you did here without hardcoding the months in the pivot table logic?

Comment: yes you are right, not in the pivot table neither during the calculations.

Comment: answer is acceptable if its solved my problem.. :)

Comment: @Love2Learn you should change your alias to **[RepLove](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522)**

Comment: @Love2Learn its Sql server 2008

Comment: @Love2Learn that is ENTIRELY the wrong way to go about it. If you want to gain rep, write good answers, take care to make sure you have a friendly attitude, and before you know it you'll have access to everything you need. Being an asshole "I'll only help if you're going to pay attention t the answer" is absolutely the wrong way to go about things.  As an example I'll point to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261062/js-function-when-keyboard-key-is-pressed/14262201#14262201 where my answer was later than most of the others and I had the most upvotes of everyone and the accept.

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh What might be very helpful in getting the syntax correct for this, is to create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data.

Comment: Contribute properly and you'll get upvotes.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the full sproc. I don't see the declaration of the @FiscalMonth table variable. Can you provide that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL to do this.  The *rough* code is going to be similar to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_sp_GetDMActivityTrackerReport]
    @CoachId VARCHAR(7),
    @Month INT,
    @FiscalYear INT
AS 
BEGIN    

INSERT @FiscalMonth (ID,Month,NbHolidays,MonthDate,TotalDays)
EXECUTE dbo._sp_GetFiscalMonths @Month, @FiscalYear

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsSum AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart)) 
                    from NonFieldTime nft
                    where datename(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) + '-'+ substring(datename(Year,nft.MonthPeriodStart),3,2) 
                        IN (SELECT Month +'-' +substring(datename(Year,MonthDate),3,2) [Months] 
                            FROM +@FiscalMonth)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart))+', 0) as '+DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart)
                    from NonFieldTime nft
                    where datename(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) + '-'+ substring(datename(Year,nft.MonthPeriodStart),3,2) 
                        IN (SELECT Month +'-' +substring(datename(Year,MonthDate),3,2) [Months] 
                            FROM +@FiscalMonth)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

select @colsSum = STUFF((SELECT distinct '+ IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart))+', 0)'
                    from NonFieldTime nft
                    where datename(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) + '-'+ substring(datename(Year,nft.MonthPeriodStart),3,2) 
                        IN (SELECT Month +'-' +substring(datename(Year,MonthDate),3,2) [Months] 
                            FROM +@FiscalMonth)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')+' as [Total Field TIME] '

set @query = 'SELECT PreparationID,CoachId,UserID, MemberID,
                    [Rep Name], ' + @colsNull + ', '+ @colsSum+' 
             from 
             (
                SELECT up.PreparationID,
                    tt.UserId [CoachId],
                    up.UserID, utm.MemberID, 
                    (ui.FirstName + '' '' + ui.LastName) AS [Rep Name],
                    DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) [Month], 
                    sum(nft.Quantity) [Days]
                FROM TransferedTime tt
                INNER JOIN UPreparation up 
                    ON tt.PreparationID = up.PreparationID 
                RIGHT JOIN UTeamMembers utm 
                    ON tt.UserId = utm.CoachID AND utm.MemberID = up.UserID
                INNER JOIN UserInfo ui 
                    ON utm.MemberID = ui.UserID
                LEFT JOIN NonFieldTime nft 
                    ON nft.UserId = tt.UserId 
                    AND tt.MonthPeriodFrom = nft.MonthPeriodStart
                    AND datename(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart) + ''-''+ substring(datename(Year,nft.MonthPeriodStart),3,2) IN 
                        (SELECT Month +''-'' +substring(datename(Year,MonthDate),3,2) [Months] 
                         FROM +@FiscalMonth)
                WHERE utm.MemberID IN (SELECT MemberID 
                                        FROM UTeamMembers 
                                        WHERE CoachID = '+@CoachId+')
                GROUP BY up.PreparationID,tt.UserId,up.UserID, utm.MemberID,
                (ui.FirstName + '' '' + ui.LastName),DateName(Month,nft.MonthPeriodStart)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Days)
                for Month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

My suggestion instead of using the temp table `@FiscalMonth` is to create a table that is permanent for this. It will be much simpler to query against a perm table rather than the temp table when using dynamic sql.  The temp table might be out of scope for the dynamic query.

Comment: It is out of scope, but yeah, work around that and this is what you want.

Comment: thanks @bluefeet it almost works the only thing i wonder is right now i have only two months data in "NonFieldTime" table i.e. December & January so it showing result for them but i have to show the rest of the months also.

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh since you are pulling the values dynamically the pivoted columns will be based on what is in your table. You would need to join on a list of all months in the year if you wanted to be sure that each month was included or use a hard-coded version of the query.

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh If you need all the months, then why did you said that having the months fixed were bad practice, that's exactly what you needed. You don't need dynamic sql for that

Comment: @lamak actually right now I have fiscalmonth starts with "April" in future it may be "June" for some other client thats why I wanted it to convert into a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

There is PIVOT XML option in Oracle that allows you to avoid hard coding. I'm not sure if there is such option in SQL Server. You can write smth lk this - also Oracle query:

```
SELECT count(decode(state,'FL',custid)) "FL"
     , count(decode(state,'NY',custid)) "NY"
     , count(decode(state,'CA',custid)) "CA"
FROM scott.customer
GROUP BY state
/
```

Replace state with month etc... 
Output:

```
FL  NY  CA
--- --- ---
0   2   0
5   0   8
```

Oracle example:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
 SELECT product_code, quantity
   FROM   pivot_test
)
PIVOT XML
(
 SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity 
  FOR (product_code) IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_code 
                        FROM   pivot_test
                       WHERE  id < 10)
)
/
```