# How to pivot query results with a grand total column for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

```
DECLARE @TimeByDay VARCHAR(max)

SET @TimeByDay = LTRIM(RTRIM(
  (
    SELECT QUOTENAME(REPLACE(LEFT(DATENAME(dw, TimeByDay), 3) + ', ' + CAST(TimeByDay AS varchar(11)),'''',''''''),'[') + ', '           
    FROM #TimesheetLineData
    GROUP BY TimeByDay
    ORDER BY TimeByDay
    FOR XML PATH('')
  )))
  SET @TimeByDay = LEFT(@TimeByDay, Len(@TimeByDay) - 1)
  --PRINT 'columns -' + @TimeByDay;

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX), @sql2 VARCHAR(MAX), @sql3 VARCHAR(MAX), @sql4 VARCHAR(MAX),@sql5 Varchar(Max),@sql6 Varchar(Max),@sql7 Varchar(Max),@sql8 Varchar(Max);

SET @sql = 'SELECT *,0 As OrderID 
        INTO ##fp_FetchTimeSheet_PWA_Data 
        FROM 
        ('

SET @sql3 = ' 
        SELECT ResourceName AS ResourceName
            , SOW
            , TaskName As [Task Name/Description]
            , ' + @TimeByDay + '

    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        ResourceName,
        SOW,    
        TaskName,
        LEFT(DATENAME(dw, TimeByDay), 3) + '', '' + CAST(TimeByDay AS varchar(11)) AS TimeByDay,
        CAST(CAST(ActualWorkBillable as decimal(8,1)) as Varchar)+ '' h''  AS PlannedWork
        FROM #TimesheetLineData'

SET @sql3=@sql3 + ') AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(PlannedWork)'
SET @sql4 = ' FOR TimeByDay IN ('+ @TimeByDay +')
    ) AS PivotTable
    ) A 
    ORDER BY ResourceName, [Task Name/Description],SOW';

EXEC  (@sql + @sql3 + @sql4)

SET @sql5 = 'INSERT INTO ##fp_FetchTimeSheet_PWA_Data 
    SELECT *,1 As OrderID FROM
        ('

SET @sql7 = ' 
        SELECT ResourceName
            , NULL As SOW               
            , ''Total Actual Work'' As [Task Name/Description]
            , ' + @TimeByDay + '
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ResourceName, 
            SOW,
            [Task Name/Description],
            LEFT(DATENAME(dw, TimeByDay), 3) + '', '' + CAST(TimeByDay AS varchar(11)) AS TimeByDay,
            TotalActualWork
        from #TimesheetLineDataSummary'

set @sql7=@sql7 + ') AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(TotalActualWork)'

SET @sql8 = ' FOR TimeByDay IN ('+ @TimeByDay +')
    ) AS PivotTable
    )A
    ORDER BY ResourceName, [Task Name/Description]';

exec  (@sql5 + @sql7 + @sql8)

SELECT *
FROM ##fp_FetchTimeSheet_PWA_Data
ORDER BY ResourceName,OrderID
```

I have the above query that uses pivot with dynamic columns as part of a stored procedure. So far, the query is working fine but what i'm struggling to achieve to add a grant total column for each returned row which would be a sum of the dynamically generated columns (in variable `@TimeByDay`)

I'm trying to follow an article here https://www.codeproject.com/articles/232181/sql-pivot-with-grand-total-column-and-row but some how, i can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Here is an [answer with getting a total column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344311/426671), as far as getting a total row - have you looking as using [ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: @bluefeet SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: The *grand total* is - in most cases! - something the presentation layer should calculate.

If you have to do this, you have two options:

1. Let your SP return the `SELECT` *as is* and place one more `SELECT`, which returns just one row with all SUMs you need. Depending on the tool you are calling this, it is possible to read several result sets with one single call to a SP.
2. Use  something like this

The code uses `UNION ALL` to add your grand total. The RowInx and sorting is needed to ensure the correct order and the *grand total* in the last place.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,val1 INT, val2 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6);

SELECT ID,val1,val2
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowInx, * FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000000,NULL,SUM(val1),SUM(val2) FROM @tbl
) AS t
ORDER BY t.RowInx
```

Comment: This gives the column totals as the last row, but what i need is the row total as the last column.

Comment: Ah, did not understand this... As you are doing this dynamically, why not add a `,col1+col2+col3 AS RowTotal` dynamically?

Comment: i have marked this as the answer because your comment above made me rethink the way i was trying to solve the problem, which led me to post this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906513/how-can-i-get-the-total-of-a-rows-dynamically-generated-columns-in-a-select-quer and i have a solution there.