# How can i get the total of a rows dynamically generated columns in a select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @DynamicColumns VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DynamicColumns = '[Mon, Oct 31 2016], [Tue, Nov  1 2016], [Wed, Nov  2 2016], [Thu, Nov  3 2016],[Many More Columns Can be Added]'
```

I have a temp table that has columns FirstName & LastName. The table will also contain dynamically generated columns depending on the parameters passed to the stored procedure. The dynamically added columns could be 10, 100 or 2.

I can access the names of the generated column in the `@DynamicColumns` variable i have declared above.

The Columns names are in the format shown above and separated by a comma (,)

PROBLEM: If i write the query below, i can get all rows i want with all the dynamically added columns.

```
SELECT * FROM ##TempTable1
```

But how can i compute the sum of the dynamically added columns and return it as an extra "Total" column for each row.

I would have writen something like

```
SELECT *, [Mon, Oct 31 2016] + [Tue, Nov  1 2016] + [Wed, Nov  2 2016] + [Thu, Nov  3 2016] AS Total
FROM ##TempTable1
```

but the columns are going to be dynamic, so that wouldn't work.(but i have access to the column names in variable `@DynamicColumns`)

What i need is something like below but how can i extract my column names from the variable `@DynamicColumns` and get their sum?

```
SELECT *, SUM(@DynamicColumns) AS Total -- the Sum of all columns in @DynamicColumns
FROM ##TempTable1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new dynamic T-SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT *, ' + REPLACE(@DynamicColumns, ',', '+') + '  AS Total 
FROM ##TempTable1;'

exec @DynamicSQLStatement
```

I have just see, that you have `,` in the column names, so you can replace `], [` instead comma.

```
REPLACE(@DynamicColumns, '], [', '] + [')
```