# JavaScript: add keyboard events (focus on window is wrong?)

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

I'm putting my hands in javascript for the first time and I can't seem to find a way to do what I need to do for a class.
We have a html file that defines a calculator and already works with mouse input.

The style and the functions are defined in separate .css and .js files. We're supposed to add keyboard-events in order to make the calculator accessible. I've been trying several options, especially from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261062/js-function-when-keyboard-key-is-pressed/14262201#14262201), but none seemed to work.

The problem is that I don't even know how to find out whether it's not working because my function is wrong or it's not working because I don't have the correct focus in my window...

I'll give an example of code below. I'll focus just on the "clear" functionality, which I'd like to assign to the backspace key (keycode=8).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>MyCalc</title>
  <link title="screen" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="calculator">
    <!-- Screen and clear key -->
    <div class="top">
      <span class="clear" onclick="clearScreen()">C</span>
      <div class="screen"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <!-- operators and other keys -->
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

where the `clearScreen` function is defined as:

```js
function clearScreen() {
  var input = document.querySelector('.screen');
  input.innerHTML = '';
}
```

I'd appreciate if someone could tell me how to bind my backspace key to that `clearScreen` function. As I mentioned above, so far I tried to paste the following code in my .js file, but with no success:

```js
function keyListener(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode;
  var input = document.querySelector('.screen');
  if (key === 8) { //this is for 'backspace'
    input.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

var el = window; //does this even work?

var eventName = 'keypress';
if (el.addEventListener) {
  el.addEventListener('click', keyListener, false);
} else if (el.attachEvent) {
  el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, keyListener);
}
```

NOTE: I'm using Google Chrome but I also did some tests in Mozilla and IE. I didn't notice any difference.

Comment: You're binding a `'click'` listener. Change it to `eventName`.

Comment: you mean simply changing "el.addEventListener('click', keyListener, false);" in "el.addEventListener('eventName', keyListener, false);" ? uhm that didn't do the trick... :O

Comment: eventName is a variable, not a string. Don't put it in quotes.