# If key pressed then, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made this game counter: https://mikesgames.neocities.org/Games/Cursor%20Counter/counter.html for my friends and I (*I'm in middle school so it doesn't have to be perfect*).

I want to have a **feature** where someone **presses the key**(cursor) the game grants the initiator 10,000 points (in my game its cursors).

I believe I will need JavaScript for this. I have a little cheat button like this-

```
<div class="button" onclick="cheat()"></div>
```

**btw** I'm using https://neocities.org

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS function when keyboard key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261062/js-function-when-keyboard-key-is-pressed)

Comment: Actually i read that question but i didn't understand any of it. I'm kinda new to javascript.

Comment: Since you elected to state "I'm in middle school so it doesn't have to be perfect" in your question, it needs to be noted that you must be at least 13 years of age to open an account on the Stack Exchange network (see https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Comment: lol im 14 but ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following Javascript to call the *cheat* method when N is pressed

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(key===78){
        cheat();
    }
}
```

If you want to add additional functionality for other keys then a useful list can be found here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/