# How to trigger a javascript function when specific key is pressed on Keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger a javascript function whenever a specific key is pressed on the keyboard, for example 
**After pressing button "A" on the keyboard, run the function "myFunction()"**

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("hey");
}
```

Comment: So bind event listener and check key

Comment: Begin by trying to solve the problem yourself; post any specific problems or questions you run into.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS function when keyboard key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261062/js-function-when-keyboard-key-is-pressed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Something similar   
 
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode !== 65) {
    return;
  }
  myFunction();
});
function myFunction() {
  alert("hey");
}
</script>
```

Comment: you just need to change the function I presented into your function

Comment: This will only work while the button has focus. There are many questions about this behavior already; please spend some time looking for those before answering.

Comment: Aight, thanks man. then, it will be easier just take  the BUTTON down, make the key can press when you focus on that page instead of a single button.

Comment: Thank You for the help.

Comment: Hey @HereticMonkey , actually it also works when the button is not focused and also when there is no button.

Comment: @iamabdm The answer was edited after I left my comment.